# Why does Django order by column number instead of column name?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have this Django ORM code:

```
queryset.filter(filters).annotate(rank=SearchRank(vectors, search_query)).order_by('-rank').distinct()
```

and Django transforms this code into that sql:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT "model_1"."id",
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ts_rank(
    "model_2"."search_vector", 
    phraseto_tsquery(query)
  ) AS "rank" 
 FROM 
   "model_1" 
 INNER JOIN "model_2" ON (
   "model_1"."id" = "model_2"."case_id"
  ) 
 WHERE 
 (
   "model_2"."search_vector" @@ (
   phraseto_tsquery(query)
 )
) 
ORDER BY 
41 ASC
```

I cant understand why Django use 41(its a number of annotated rank column) instead of column name and i cant find any Django docs that describe this logic.

Django version: **5.0.2**

Comment: Probably because it can? It's an internal of the ORM, why does this matter?